# How to change the color of a tab based on cell value on that sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have several sheets in workbook.  Each sheet has a date in cell U2.  I would like to have all of the cells with a weekday value in U2 to have a tab color of green, and the tabs of the worksheets which have a weekend value in U2 to be yellow.  I have found how to change the color of the tab, but don't know how to specifically tell it "Sheet4" tab color green.  I am looking for the code to look like:

```
For each sht in Thisworkbook.worksheets
  If format(sht.Renge("U2"),"DDD") = "Saturday" _
    or format(sht.Renge("U2"),"DDD") = "Sunday" then
    sht.Tab.ColorIndex = "yellow"
  else
    sht.Tab.ColorIndex = "blue"
  end if
Next
```

Here is the code I have been working with:

```
Sub sbColorAllSheetTab()
    'Declaration
    Dim iCntr, sht As Worksheet

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Holds the colorIndex number
    iCntr = 2

    'looping throgh the all the sheets of the workbook
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        'Debug.Print Format(sht.Range("U2"), "DDD")  'Tried to check value on sheet - failed
        iCntr = iCntr + 1

        'Applying the colors to Sheet tabs - works
        sht.Tab.ColorIndex = 10 'iCntr

        'Tried to print the value, but didn't work'
        'If I can confirm it sees the correct value in the sheet I can interrogate the value
        'Debug.Print sht.Name  '.Range("U2")
        Debug.Print sht.Range("U2") 'Failed
    Next

   Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
   ' Error handling code
   Beep
   Resume Next
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: use `If WeekDay(Range("U2")) = 7 or If WeekDay(Range("U2")) = 1 then`

Comment: Hi Scott,  I think you are close, but not quit.  I think the problem is in cell U2 on each sheet.  The first sheet (named 01) is the first of the month coded as 1/1/2016 and is a custom format of mmm,d,yyyy.  The second sheet2 U2 is '01'!U2+DayOfMonth-1; DayOfMonth is VALUE(MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("]",CELL("filename"))+1,255)).  I tried Value(sht.Range("U2"), CInt, and CDbl, all not working.  However, when I hard code the dates in as 1/2/2015, 1/3/2015, etc, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of your request ("I am looking for the code to look like:"), your code was very close.

I only changed:

1. Your date format (from "DDD" to "DDDD")
2. A misspelling of Range
3. Substituted the integer for the tab color in place of your string

The closest thing to your code that I got to work is:

```
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  If Format(sht.Range("U2"), "DDDD") = "Saturday" _
    Or Format(sht.Range("U2"), "DDDD") = "Sunday" Then
    sht.Tab.ColorIndex = 6 'yellow
  Else
    sht.Tab.ColorIndex = 5 'blue
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the typo corrections, but I got the same failure.  When the date in U2 on the first four sheets is hard coded it works fine, but when it is the formula '01'!U2+DayOfMonth-1 as stated above, it makes the tab blue.  So, 1/1/2016 (Fri) to 1/4/2016 (Mon) are hard coded and get the correct color.  1/9/2016 is a saturday, so it should change the tab color to yellow, but it and all of the rest are blue.  It appears to need a conversion of some sort.

Comment: I did MsgBox Format(sht.Range("U2"), "DDDD") and each sheet which had the formula came out as the first sheet whcih had the formula, e.g. the msgbox presented "Tuesday" for all of the remaining sheets.  The hard coded dated cells each came out correctly as "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday".

Comment: BTW, if anyone has a cleaner way of solving this problem I am open to your suggestions.

Comment: If I run my code above with "U2" dates as formulas it still works as designed.  That tells me that your date formulas aren't calculating to dates, so to the IF statement isn't Saturday or Sunday and therefore colors the tab blue.  To find out what the date formula calculates to, send it to a variable.  I believe you'll find the issue in your date formula above ('01'!U2+DayOfMonth-1)